# How do you look up where identifiers are defined in Coq efficiently?

Tags: emacs, coq, coqide, proof-general

In most IDEs or text editors, you can right-click a term and it takes you to the file where that term is defined. CoqIDE doesn't seem to have that, so I've been doing `coqdoc myfile.v --html`, then going to the generated HTML docs. But the only clickable terms in that file are for Coq Standard Library. Terms defined by ssreflect (for example) aren't clickable.

Is there a standard way to be able to quickly lookup where some term/identifier is defined (and the source code for it) when in a Coq file? Either in the CoqIDE or in emacs + ProofGeneral (I'm using CoqIDE, but I'd switch if emacs/ProofGeneral had this ability).

Or is the standard way to generate docs for every Coq project and dependency you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you highlight a term, and do Queries -> Locate, or you evaluate `Locate some_identifier.`, you will get the full name of the constant.  If you know where the dependencies are installed, this will tell you where to look for the identifier.

Edit: If you want the definition of the identifier, you can `Print` it.  If you just want it's type, you can use `About`, or `Check` (which also accepts expressions, and not just identifiers).

Comment: That's close, but Queries -> Locate on `finType` gives this: "Notation Ssreflect.fintype.Finite.Exports.finType" (which is helpful). But is there a way for it to link me to the source code, or the docs somehow?
So instead it would go to http://coqfinitgroup.gforge.inria.fr/doc/fintype.html#Finite.Exports.finType (or something along those lines, maybe the local copy of ssreflect source code or similar)

Comment: Follow up in #coq IRC. Jason said "No, I don't think there's a way to do that, currently. The source files don't even get installed, though I think they might be fixing that soon (or in the next beta).  It might be possible to do with https://itu.dk/research/tomeso/coqoon/, though I haven't tried it."

Comment: He also said about his typical workflow which was helpful (for reference): "I use `Locate`.  If it's my own file, I open the relevant source file.  If it's Coq.*, I either go to github.coq/coq/coq, or to a local copy of the Coq source code.  If it's a library I installed, I go to the directory I installed it from.  But, more frequently, I just `Print` the identifier, or use `About` or `Check`, instead, which gives me the full definition (less any documentation or formatting).  The type signature, plus sometimes the definition, is often enough."

Comment: got this error `No object of basename cbn`...weird no? `Locate cbn.`

Comment: `Locate` does not work very well for components of the Ltac AST (nor for Tactic Notations, for that matter).  If you want to find cbn, you can use `git grep` on the Coq sources.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool working on top of Proof General, called [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq). It has the jump to definition feature bound to the `M-.` keyboard shortcut by default.

It can jump to the definition under cursor (even to the standard library) only if the module containing the definition is required with `Require` command or its variant.