# What do the consecutive in's in Coq do and eval & red & Idtac do?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I know in OCaml the syntax

```
let x = val in exp
```

means `x` has the value `v` when in expression `exp`.

But what does something like

```
let add_left_red := eval red in add_left in  (* reduce add_left, but leave goal alone *)
  idtac add_left_red.
```

I assume it does this:

- gives the identifier `add_left_red` the output of `eval red`
- then that `add_left_red` is that value in `add_left`
- AND in `idtac add_left_red`

Is that what it does?

---

Fyi I also have no idea what that line does. Especially cuz googling `eval` and `red` gave nothing useful.

[Idtac did see](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.idtac):

```
Tacticidtac  ident  ​   string  ​   natural *
Leaves the proof unchanged and prints the given tokens. Strings and naturals are printed literally. If ident is an Ltac variable, its contents are printed; if not, it is an error.
```

What do those composoble blocks do?

---

Context whole script

```
Fixpoint add_left (n m : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | O => m
  | S p => S (add_left p m)
  end.
  
Lemma demo_1 :
  forall (n : nat),
    add_left n O = n.
Proof.
  intros.                                     (* goal : add_left n O = n *)  
  let add_left_red := eval red in add_left in (* reduce add_left, but leave goal alone *)
  idtac add_left_red.                         (* print the result *)
  (* Print eval. gives error *) 
  Print red.
  Print add_left_red.
  admit.
Abort.
```

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml, there is only one notion of computation, but in Coq, we may want to play with several such notions, because we sometimes want to compute or simplify only progressively the expressions we are looking at.

So there is a command, akin to `Compute` which makes it possible to take a term, and compute it only partially.  This command as an `in` keyword in the middle.

Here is an example:

```
Require Import Arith.
Eval cbn[fact] in fact 10.
```

Here the result shows the computation of fact 10, but only insofar that the multiplications it performs are exposed, but not computed themselves.

Sometimes, in a tactic you want to do just this computation, so will need to use a variant of this `eval ... in ...` construct (this time with a lower case initial), which is designed for use in tactics.

```
let x := eval cbn[fact] in (fact 10) in change (fact 10) with x.
```

So in your goal, fact 10 is replaced by (10 * 9 ...)

if it were in OCaml, you would not bother explaining that you want a partial computation so you would write only `let x = fact 10 in ...` .

So this is the reason why the keyword appears twice.  The first time to separate the computation mechanism you want to apply to the expression, and the second time to separate the expression that is evaluated from the expression where the variable will be used.

Here is an example where the tactic is being used:

```
Require Import Arith.
Lemma toto : fact 7 = 5040.
let x := eval cbn[fact] in (fact 7) in change (fact 7) with x.
```

(tested with coq-8.14)

Comment: what does `cbn[fact]` do? In particular I am puzzle about the bracket `[` syntax given to a tactic (receiving the factorize function I pressume).

Comment: what does a lower case eval mean? when I try to print it I get `eval not a defined object.` Where is the definition of this? Is it a tactic or command?

Comment: I think your example has a bug. I can't run it and get this error `Syntax error: 'with' or 'in' expected (in [binder_tactic]).`. But I can't find the `eval` tactic command see comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823528/how-do-you-lookup-the-definition-or-implementation-of-coq-proof-tactics so I am unsure how to fix it or proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: truly sorry for posting an example that contained a syntax error.  The message is now fixed.

Comment: `cbn` is a *reduction tactic*, a procedure for performing partial computation.  `cbn [fact]` instructs coq to expand only the function `fact` according to its definition, no other function (so in particular, not the multiplication function).  `cbn` is short for *call-by-name*, a strategy that prescribes in which order the functions are considered for expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the realted `Eval RED in Term` is key. Do that first.

- `eval`: ref: [What do the consecutive in's in Coq do and eval & red & Idtac do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352757/what-do-the-consecutive-ins-in-coq-do-and-eval-red-idtac-do/71354083#71354083)

```
I think its 
eval RED in TERM
```

Example:

```
  Require Import Arith.
  Lemma toto : fact 3 = 6.
  let x :=    (*set the output of eval RED in TERM to id/var x*)
  (eval cbn[fact] in (fact 3))  (* partially reduce fact 3 *)
  in (* output of "let x := (eval RED in TERM)" goes here *)
  idtac x. (* final expression to evaluate with x *)

  (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))
```